# Android MediaRecorder crashed after set profile

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I have a problem to save a video to sdcard using MediaRecorder on android.

My code works fie until I reach the line that set the profile to high quality.

This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_testing);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        //setupActionBar();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

        SurfaceView cameraView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        holder = cameraView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        intentTestResults = new Intent(this, TestResultsAct.class);

        TestPB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBarTest);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(mProgressStatus < 100){
                    if(mProgressStatus == 1)
                        record();
                    if(mProgressStatus == 35)
                        record();
                    mProgressStatus += 1;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TestPB.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
        //
    }
```

while

```
 private void initRecorder() {
        camera.unlock();

        recorder.setCamera(camera);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
        recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Frames/videocapture_example.mp4");
        recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(300000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
    }
    private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }

    void record()
    {
        if (recording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recording = false;
            camera.lock();
            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.unlock();
            recorder.release();
            //finish();
        } else {
            recording = true;
            initRecorder();
            prepareRecorder();
            recorder.start();
        }
    }
```

My problem came after this line : recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);

This is the logcat:

```
12-26 10:37:43.670: E/MediaRecorder(6046): try to set the audio encoder without setting the audio source first
    12-26 10:38:35.150: W/dalvikvm(6046): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fee2a0)
    12-26 10:38:37.065: E/AndroidRuntime(6046): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-794
    12-26 10:38:37.065: E/AndroidRuntime(6046): java.lang.IllegalStateException
    12-26 10:38:37.065: E/AndroidRuntime(6046):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(Native Method)
    12-26 10:38:37.065: E/AndroidRuntime(6046):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.setProfile(MediaRecorder.java:370)
    12-26 10:38:37.065: E/AndroidRuntime(6046):     at com.example.homedevice.SampleTestingAct.initRecorder(SampleTestingAct.java:124)
    12-26 10:38:37.065: E/AndroidRuntime(6046):     at com.example.homedevice.SampleTestingAct.record(SampleTestingAct.java:155)
    12-26 10:38:37.065: E/AndroidRuntime(6046):     at com.example.homedevice.SampleTestingAct$2.run(SampleTestingAct.java:90)
    12-26 10:38:37.065: E/AndroidRuntime(6046):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    12-26 10:38:47.555: E/MediaRecorder(6046): stop called in an invalid state: 4
```

The exception that was written is :
 java.lang.IllegalStateException

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT1(with sound permission):**

```
private void initRecorder() {
    camera.unlock();

    recorder.setCamera(camera);
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    //recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
    //recorder.setVideoSize(1920, 1080);
    //recorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile
            .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
    recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Frames/videocapture_example.mp4");
    recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
    recorder.setMaxFileSize(300000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
}
```

**Edit2(logcat) :**
This is the logcat

```
    12-26 11:32:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(18552): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1016
12-26 11:32:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(18552): java.lang.IllegalStateException
12-26 11:32:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(18552):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(Native Method)
12-26 11:32:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(18552):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setProfile(MediaRecorder.java:357)
12-26 11:32:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(18552):    at com.example.homedevice.SampleTestingAct.initRecorder(SampleTestingAct.java:127)
12-26 11:32:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(18552):    at com.example.homedevice.SampleTestingAct.record(SampleTestingAct.java:158)
12-26 11:32:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(18552):    at com.example.homedevice.SampleTestingAct$2.run(SampleTestingAct.java:90)
12-26 11:32:43.170: E/AndroidRuntime(18552):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
setOutputFormat called in an invalid state: 4
threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fee2a0).
```

Answer (score 1):

setProfile() function.

> It always calls setAudioEncoder() so if you don't set the audio source
>   it will crash.

try to include this in your code:

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT); 
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT); 

recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
```

Explanation:

`CamcorderProfile` also sets audio properties (such as Codec, BitRate, SampleRate,...) so you need to set an Audio Source before calling it, that's why the app crashed. If you don't want to record audio try the next code:

```
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setVideoSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFile(PATH);
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(SURFACE);

recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

Comment: can you check if the microphone is not being used by some other application.

Comment: Now it fall in the `recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);` line. the exaption is : `java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.`
EDIT: I tried also to work without sound but then it falls in the start line `recorder.start();`, with this exaption: `java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.`

Comment: also have you added the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: No , I don't use it and all the applications are close.

Comment: After I add the permission, again it fall in the set profile line.
this is the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException`

Comment: i hope you are including the above code before setProfile. can you edit the question to show your updated code. also i coundn't see the full exception or illegal state number in your last comment

Comment: I added the full logcat to the question.

Comment: Maybe the thread that runs in the same time should be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, `recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QU‌​ALITY_HIGH))` does already set the `AudioEncoder` and `VideoEncoder` for you already.

Remove those encoders and you should be fine after that.